# Printing topic distribution after LDA using gensim

Tags: python, lda, gensim

I have made a sample program for getting topic distribution per document after doing LDA using gensim

```
documents = ["Apple is releasing a new product", 
             "Amazon sells many things",
             "Microsoft announces Nokia acquisition"]   

stoplist=["is","are","am","were","a","me","I"]

texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist] for document in documents]
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=2, update_every=1, chunksize=10000, passes=1)
lda.print_topics(2)
```

But the program is not printing anything.. Any changes required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone needs , found the answer  .. logger has to be used before

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```